# How to change output format of text extracted from apache tika?

Tags: java, pdf, apache-tika, text-extraction

I used apache tika to extract text from pdf using the code:

`

```
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, context);
```

`

the output is as follows:

`

```
<p>Level 1 

Level 2 

Level 3 

 Level 4 

 Level 5 

 Level 6 

  Level 7 

  Level 8 

  Level 9 

 Level 10 

 Level 11 

Level 12 

Level 13    </p>
```

`

Is there any way I can get the output by configuring the pdf parser so that in the output each level# in enclosed within individual paragraph tag?
For example:

```
<p>Level 1</p>
<p>Level 2</p>
```

Each level in the pdf can actually represent a sentence or paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// Get string data
String data = handler.toString();
// Remove tags or other things (depends on your needs)
data = data.replace("<p>","");
data = data.replace("</p>","");
// Now it looks like: String data ="Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 Level 5 Level 6 ... ";
String newdata = "";
// Split string in all places contain [number]+[blank space]
for (String s: data.split("(?<=[0-9])(?=" ")")) {
    // append with desired strings
    s =  "<p>"+s+"</p>";
    // and store modified data
    newdata += s;
}
```

So, if you need, you can put "\n" additionally after tag `"</p>"`. 
Also you can output all `s` strings one by one if you need.

I hope this was helpful. Good luck.

Comment: i am really sorry to post such a vague question, but each level# represents a hierarchy and may contain some more text. Level 1 can actually represent a sentence so splitting on the basis of blank space will not work. Additionally, is there any way to achieve the result by configuring the tika pdf parser.

Comment: You need a custom Tika Config, if you want to do non-standard things, such as force certain parsers or exclude certain parsers, or make parsers handle non-standard mime types and so on. So ... Normally you'd do that with a `tika-config.xml` file. You can see here on the [Tika wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/CompositeParserDiscussion) what you are able to do. To override standart parser visit [this](http://tika.apache.org/1.14/configuring.html#Configuring_Parsers)